Problem with importing Python module in VsCode
I'm learning Python and wanted to make a snack store management application.
When I try to import authenticate logic, it shows the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/mac/Dev/Learn_python/btl/snack_app/source_code/views/login_screen.py", line 5, in <module>
import source_code.controllers.authenticate as auth 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'source_code'

My import code looks like this:
import controllers.authenticate as auth
I use Venv and in the image is the structure of the project

I think vscode confirmed the module exists because it shows green in the code like this

I don't know what's wrong.
I tried adding source_code.controllers and the error became ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'source_code'.
I activated Venv (If that matters).

Somehow this problem comes from my VScode or my computer.
I downloaded Pycharm and no problem since.

Last time when I faced this issue, I remember I had to change the location from where I was running the code.
Opening the "snack_app" directory and running the python app from there solved my error.

I tried opening the file from the snack_app folder and the problem is still there.

Try moving the python file outside the folder. If you place the file in snack_app then you can run
from source_code.controllers import authenticate as auth

Can you give me more info on where I should move the file? As in the picture, my login file is inside the views folder, the authenticate file is in side the controllers folders and they both inside the source_code folder.

I apologise, I redid my answer which is hopefully more clear, and would fix your import error. Please let me know if it does not work

Are you using a virtual environment, If you are not
Its better to use a virtual environment per each project to avoid import issues like this...
install virtualenv globally
pip install virtualenv


then try on windows
python -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment

on mac or linux
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment

then you activate it
source /path/to/new/virtual/environment/bin/activate

then you can pip install all modules and import them without issues

As I stated in the question, I activated Venv and the problem persists.

pip install virtualenv is not needed to use python -m venv.

yh my bad i somehow missed that when reading through
